# Short simple code. Weird behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I'm new to gcd and multithreading / concurrency / parallelism. I wrote this example project to test some things out. I have 3 methods, a list of image urls, and an imageView in the interface.

Each method does essentially the same thing, with minor variations.

loadAllImagesSlow() loops through the image urls, creating the NSData from each url, creating a UIImage and setting the imageView's image to that image.

loadAllImagesFast() dispatches that entire task to a global concurrent queue.

newMethod() loops through the image urls and dispatches each task to a global concurrent queue. This was the fastest! :D Exciting stuff. For me anyway.

When I run loadAllImagesFast or newMethod, I see the interface quickly cycle through each image, ending at the last one. But for loadAllImagesSlow, I don't see any images; only the last image appears at the very end.

I believe loadAllImagesSlow is running on the main thread (serial queue), because i don't get responses when I tap the screen (the other functions don't block the UI). But since it's a serial queue, I don't understand why the imageView doesn't display the images one at a time. Since the main queue is serial, everything's supposed to be executed before following code. But that isn't happening with the imageView's image being set.

Any ideas why that might be? I don't need this for a particular project; I'm simply trying to understand the behaviour.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    var urlArray = [

        "https://img0.ndsstatic.com/wallpapers/76df262f429c799124461286c5ee64b1_large.jpeg",
        "https://www.walldevil.com/wallpapers/a74/olivia-wilde-women-actresses-green-eyes-ponytails.jpg",
        "https://richestcelebrities.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Olivia-Wilde-Net-Worth.jpg",
        "https://cdn.pcwallart.com/images/olivia-wilde-wallpaper-3.jpg",
        "https://kingofwallpapers.com/olivia-wilde/olivia-wilde-006.jpg",
        "https://img0.ndsstatic.com/wallpapers/b39ca6a58368a76a92d56739d6e2da31_large.jpeg"

    ]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)


        print("starting")
        self.loadAllImagesSlow()

    }

    func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("tap")
    }


    func loadAllImagesSlow() { // takes around 4 seconds. UI is unresponsive throughout. Only last image gets shown

        let startTime = Date()
        for each in self.urlArray {

            let url = URL(string: each)

            do {

                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
                self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)

            } catch {
                print("error")
            }


        }
        let endTime = Date()
        let executionTime = endTime.timeIntervalSince(startTime)
        print("Execution time: \(executionTime)")
    }


    func loadAllImagesFast() { // takes around 4 seconds, but UI is responsive! Cycles through the images!

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {

            let startTime = Date()


            for each in self.urlArray {

                let url = URL(string: each)

                do {

                    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url!)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
                    }

                } catch {
                    print("error")
                }


            }

            let endTime = Date()
            let executionTime = endTime.timeIntervalSince(startTime)
            print("Execution time: \(executionTime)")

        }


    }


    func newMethod() { // much much faster than 'loadAllImagesFast'

        // This method harnesses the power of the concurrent queue by dispatching lots of smaller tasks that run concurrently, rather than dispatching one large task that runs concorruntly alongside nothing else in that queue; essentially, sequientially, on a seaprate queue.

        for each in self.urlArray {

            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                let url = URL(string: each)

                do {
                    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url!)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
                    }

                } catch {
                    print("error")
                }
            }


        }


    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for editing my question Bryan. But lol I didn't see any harm in saying thank you at the end.

Comment: Answer is quite simple download blocks main ui so it's not able to update the image . So only we are using other 2ways you mentioned for better ui update to user

Comment: @Vinodh, but the image would get set when each download finishes no?

Comment: When it try to set image a new download will be initiated in the main thread which block ui. But for the last image updation there are no download task pending so it's showing last image

Comment: @Vinodh, oh I see! So the next download task starts before the image view got set with the new image? But I thought this was a serial queue in that one thing must finish before the next thing starts. What's going on there?

Comment: By default it's not you can achieve it using GCD or Nsoperation queue